# Firebase cloud messaging is not working in both background and killed state in iPhone SE(iOS 14) - Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase cloud messaging is not working in both background and killed state when I am running my app in iPhone SE (iOS 14). I am using the following json structure for posting the notification.

```
{
   "to":"/topics/Test",
   "priority":"high",
   "content_available":true,
   "data":{
      "data1":"value1",
      "data2":"value2",
      "data3":"value3"
   }
}
```

It would be great if you can provide a solution.

Comment: What is the guy that you so-call 'Firebase remote notification'?  Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: Firebase cloud messaging is not working in both background and killed state when I am running my app in iPhone SE (iOS 14). I am using the following json structure for posting the notification.

{ "to":"/topics/Test", "priority":"high", "content_available":true, "data":{ "data1":"value1", "data2":"value2", "data3":"value3" } }.

Comment: @ElTomato I have updated to Firebase Cloud Messaging